# Why is my go handler not producing valid FormData?

Tags: go, multipartform-data

I'm tinkering around trying to get a server written in go to respond to a "mime/multipart" form with a "mime/multipart" form.

With the code below, I'm getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Could not parse content as FormData.`

My go looks like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    req.ParseMultipartForm(2097152)
    mw := multipart.NewWriter(resp)
    mw.WriteField("name", req.FormValue("user_name"))
    mw.WriteField("email", req.FormValue("user_email"))
    mw.WriteField("message", req.FormValue("user_message"))
    resp.Header().Set("Content-Type", mw.FormDataContentType())
    mw.Close()
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

My browser code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Your first HTML form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
    </head>

    <body>

<form name="theForm" method="post">
 <ul>
  <li>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="msg">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
  </li>
  <li class="button">
    <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
  </li>
 </ul>
</form>
      
      <pre id="response"></pre>
      
<script>
const form = document.forms["theForm"];

form.addEventListener( 'submit', function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const fd = new FormData(form);
  fetch('/form-handler', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: fd
  })
  .then(response => response.formData())
  .then(data => document.getElementById("response").innerText = JSON.stringify(data));
});
  
  
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

If I change the JavaScript to `.then(response => response.text)`, I get what looks like the right response, so not sure if there's a missing CRLF at the end or what?

Comment: "I'm tinkering around trying to get a server written in go to respond to a "mime/multipart" form with a "mime/multipart" form." - (I'm assuming your repetition wasn't a typo, but is intentional): your premise is mistaken: web-browsers do not (generally) support multipart responses - only multipart requests.

Comment: While `document.forms` isn't officially deprecated, it's definitely in the DOM's _very_-old early years. You should prefer `document.getElementById` instead (because `name=""` does not uniquely identify an element, only `id=""` does).

Comment: While the `<form action="">` attribute is not required, it's invariably a good idea to always specify an explicit `action` URI, just in case your `<form>` is rendered in a page at an address that does not expect `POST` requests.

Comment: Why are you using the older `.then()` approach instead of the far superior and modern `async function` approach?

Comment: @Dai after testing this locally reading multipart responses seem to work, at least in Chrome. Though the mozilla docs do mention this is mostly used when intercepting requests by service workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/formData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move `resp.Header().Set("Content-Type", mw.FormDataContentType())` to above the first write. Like so:

```golang
func handler(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    req.ParseMultipartForm(2097152)
    mw := multipart.NewWriter(resp)
    resp.Header().Set("Content-Type", mw.FormDataContentType())
    mw.WriteField("name", req.FormValue("user_name"))
    mw.WriteField("email", req.FormValue("user_email"))
    mw.WriteField("message", req.FormValue("user_message"))
    mw.Close()
}
```

HTTP headers can't be modified after the first write to the [`ResponseWriter`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter). If no `Content-Type` is set at that point it defaults to `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` which the browser can't parse since it needs the boundary which is given in the `Content-Type` header

Comment: Many thanks Dylan. As a go newbie, I suspected I'd made some simple mistake.

Comment: No worries, it is a very common mistake that even long time users run into from time to time. Same goes for setting a status code after you have already started writing the response.